# What does WCF Client Session mean?

Tags: wcf, session, servlets, client

I have WCF WebService hosted in IIS with **InstanceMode = PerSession** and **ConcurrencyMode = Single**. I am invoking this wcf service from Java Servlet and sending request sequentially (so far so good).

Now when I access this via IE/Chrome/Firefox etc, it should supposedly just create on instances of my WCF Service for one client window I have opened but IIS is creating multiple instances of it which takes quite long time to instantiate as my services is internally connected to a legacy system.

Or did I completely misunderstand the client session? What does WCF Client session mean? And who defines its boundary, can I dictate its boundary from my web app code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the article on code project useful in regards to this question [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188749/WCF-Sessions-Brief-Introduction)

Session is a well understood term for all of us and as per our common understanding, it is (well, less or more) some duration in which entities recognize each other. Some of us might have played with it in ASP.NET as well. The concept is almost similar in WCF although the technique and usage are a bit different.

In WCF, there is always a service class instance that handles incoming service requests. These instances may already be there (at server when request arrives) or may be created as needed. In WCF, the concept of session is mainly to manage these service instances so that server can be utilized in an optimized way. At the server, there is one special class named InstanceContext that creates/loads service class instance and dispatches requests to it. The correlation can be perceived as:

You can see here how stuff is engaged. When some request arrives, it is routed to service instance via instance context. Suppose there is a hit of thousand requests, then service will have to create thousand instance contexts (which in turn will create thousand service instances) to handle these requests. If requests are served in this way, then service is called PERCALL service as each request is served by a new instance context and service instance object (call them as service objects onwards). Consider there is a client that made 100 requests. If service identifies this client and always serves it by a dedicated service object, then this type of service will be known as PERSESSION service as it recognizes the client and serves it by a single instance of service object. On the other hand, if all the requests irrespective of client are served by a single instance of service objects, then the service will be known as SINGLETON service. The following pictures summarize the concept: THE LINK ABOVE WILL HAVE MORE INFO.

Comment: Thanks for the Top Answer , glad you found it useful.

Comment: I hate to bleat about link only answers but please quote the relevant parts of this article. Nothing in this answer makes me want to go there - _"You might find..."_ Great! It might also be dead tomorrow.

Comment: Added more notes to the answer @Gusdor

Answer (score 2):

Sessions in WCF are initiated by client through opening channel and closed once that channel is closed of faulted. So, if you're seeing multiple instance on the service (however, not sure how did you confirm there're multiple instances) it's because there'd multiple connection/channels opened to service.

Here's the MSDN article which may help. Pasting relevant excerpt from it,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx

WCF sessions have the following main conceptual features:
• They are explicitly initiated and terminated by the calling application (the WCF client).

• Messages delivered during a session are processed in the order in which they are received.

• Sessions correlate a group of messages into a conversation. Different types of correlation are possible. For instance, one session-based channel may correlate messages based on a shared network connection while another session-based channel may correlate messages based on a shared tag in the message body. The features that can be derived from the session depend on the nature of the correlation.

• There is no general data store associated with a WCF session.

HTH,
Amit Bhatia

Comment: Thanks for the information this clear quite more stuff. Actually in the WCF Service Constructor I am instantiating a Legacy object and I noticed in the log where the object has been created multiple times for each thread (which is correct) i.e. one WCF Instance=One Legacy Object. I would like to keep it that way as my legacy object can not be accessed by two threads simultaneously but they can coincide side by side in multiple threads. Currently my Java client is just a hacked up version and I am looking for the information so that each client connection access single WCF Instance...